# Convert Lens' a b into Lens' a (Maybe b)

Tags: haskell, lenses, haskell-lens

I have several data structures like

```hs
data Data1 = Data1
    { _data1Field :: Int
    -- More fields
    } deriving (Eq, Show)
makeLenses ''Data1

data Data2 = Data2
    { _data2Field :: Int
    -- More fields
    } deriving (Eq, Show)
makeLenses ''Data2

-- More similar data types
```

So I decided to write a simple type class to make it easier to compose

```hs
class HasField a where
    field :: Lens' a Int

instance HasField Data1 where
    field = data1Field

instance HasField Data2 where
    field = data2Field
```

But then I ran into the problem that some of these structures have the corresponding field as optional

```hs
data Data3 = Data3
    { _data3Field :: Maybe Int
    -- More fields
    } deriving (Eq, Show)
makeLenses ''Data3
```

And now I can no longer use the type class.  Since there are about the same number of data types that have that field optional as not, I decided that it'd be better to change the typeclass:

```hs
class HasField a where
    field :: Lens' a (Maybe Int)

instance HasField Data3 where
    field = data3Field
```

But since I'm not very experienced with the lens library, I'm stuck figuring out how to make this new lens work with the types for `Data1` and `Data2`.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to view it and get a `Maybe Int` value for any type, and when setting I'd like `Just x` to set the field to `x` for `Data1` and `Data2` and be a no-op for those two types when passed `Nothing`.

Is this possible using existing combinators or am I going to have to write the lens myself?  I'm fine doing so, but the majority of existing tutorials use TH and gloss over the details of writing one by hand.

I'm using GHC 7.6.3 and `lens` 3.10.

Comment: You can't really do it at all because it's an illegal lens. Lens law: `view l (set l x s) = x`, so if you set it to `Nothing` you must get `Nothing` when you view it.

Comment: It might be that you actually want a `Traversal`, though (which is like a lens onto 0 or more values, rather than just one value). When you have a `Traversal` you can use `preview` to view a `Maybe` and `set` to set.

Comment: @shachaf How would I write the `Traversal` for this?  Also, would it be a problem if there are multiple fields like this for these records?

Comment: @shachaf Alternatively, what would be some good reading material to help me understand how to write these kinds of `Traversal`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a follow up to shachaf

```
class HasFieldA d where
  field :: Traversal' d Int

instance HasFieldA Data1 where
  field = data1Field -- Lens's are Traversals

instance HasFieldA Data3 where
  field = data3Field . _Just
```

And then the `^?` operator or the `^..` operator

```
getField :: HasFieldA d => d -> Maybe Int
getField = d ^? field -- or preview field d
```

to get it.

To set optional fields, you'd need another function

```
class SetFieldA d where
  setField :: Setter' d Int
instance SetFieldA Data3 where
  setField = set data3Field . Just
```

Comment: This doesn't allow changing a Nothing field value to a Just field value though

Comment: @bennofs is correct.  This lets me set the field for `Data1` and `Data2`, but not for `Data3`.

Comment: @bennofs @bheklilr if we did this than we'd break the laws of a traversal. We need to leave the same number of targets as we started with an if we set a `Nothing` field, then subsequent traversals are affected.

Comment: @jozefg Then is there a way to still satisfy the lens laws and have an easy to use combinator that works for both?  Or am I just going down the wrong path and trying to make lenses do things they aren't supposed to?

Comment: @bheklilr I think you are. I'd use this for now and see where that get's you

Comment: What you have works other than setting the optional fields.  I'm now faced with the decision of breaking the lens laws and having it work in an inconsistent manner (potentially coming back to haunt me in the future) or conforming to the laws and sacrificing brevity and convenience.

Comment: @bheklilr Consider defining a new typeclass with `setField :: Setter' d Int` that does clobber `Nothing`s. Then you have an extra typeclass/name (ick), but can still write generic code & have the lens laws